# Delete hosted zone resource record set with PHP on amazon

Tags: php, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I can't figure out how to delete hosted zone resource record set with Amazon PHP sdk.

So my code is following

```
public function __construct(\ConsoleOutput $stdout = null, \ConsoleOutput $stderr = null, \ConsoleInput $stdin = null) {
    parent::__construct($stdout, $stderr, $stdin);

    /** @var \Aws\Route53\Route53Client route53Client */
    $this->route53Client = Route53Client::factory([
        'version'     => '2013-04-01',
        'region'      => 'eu-west-1',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => <my-key>,
            'secret' => <my-secret-key>
        ]
    ]);
}
```

And this is my function for deleting resource record set

```
private function deleteResourceRecordSet() {

    $response = $this->route53Client->changeResourceRecordSets([
        'ChangeBatch'  => [
            'Changes' => [
                [
                    'Action'            => 'DELETE',
                    'ResourceRecordSet' => [
                        'Name'            => 'pm-bounces.subdomain.myDomain.com.',
                        'Region'          => 'eu-west-1',
                        'Type'            => 'CNAME',
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'HostedZoneId' => '/hostedzone/<myHostedZoneId>'
    ]);
    var_dump($response);
    die();
}
```

And the error I'm keep getting is

```
Error executing "ChangeResourceRecordSets" on "https://route53.amazonaws.com/2013-04-01/hostedzone/<myHostedZoneId>/rrset/"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://route53.amazonaws.com/2013-04-01/hostedzone/<myHostedZoneId>/rrset/` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-04-01/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Co (truncated...)
 InvalidInput (client): Invalid request: Expected exactly one of [AliasTarget, all of [TTL, and ResourceRecords], or TrafficPolicyInstanceId], but found none in Change with [Action=DELETE, Name=pm-bounces.subdomain.myDomain.com., Type=CNAME, SetIdentifier=null] - <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-04-01/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidInput</Code><Message>Invalid request: Expected exactly one of [AliasTarget, all of [TTL, and ResourceRecords], or TrafficPolicyInstanceId], but found none in Change with [Action=DELETE, Name=pm-bounces.subdomain.myDomain.com., Type=CNAME, SetIdentifier=null]</Message>
```

So what exactly is minimum required set of params so I will be available to delete resource record from hosted zone? If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I have figure it out. If you wan't to delete resource record set from hosted zones, then the code/function for deleting record set should look like following

```
private function deleteResourceRecordSet($zoneId, $name, $ResourceRecordsValue, $recordType, $ttl) {

    $response = $this->route53Client->changeResourceRecordSets([
        'ChangeBatch'  => [
            'Changes' => [
                [
                    'Action'            => 'DELETE',
                    "ResourceRecordSet" => [
                        'Name'            => $name,
                        'Type'            => $recordType,
                        'TTL'             => $ttl,
                        'ResourceRecords' => [
                            $ResourceRecordsValue // should be reference array of all resource records set
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'HostedZoneId' => $zoneId
    ]);
}
```